# Visual Studio Properties Manager - how to get a multi-line entry for string field?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

On my Custom Control, I have a string property.
When modifying this property in the Property Manager in Visual Studio, I would like to have a multi-line text box pop up. As the Text property for a Button does - clicking the arrow at the right of the entry box brings up an entry window where multi-line entries can be made.
Is this done with using an attribute tag on the property? If so, where do I find details about it?

Comment: You should add the designer code you have for your control (to your question).  It might fire of some Synapses in readers.  I may have done this about 10 or 15 years ago, but I don't remember very much

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,1233

Comment: @Hans - that is it!  I could not find where the source code is located - now I know. Thanks much!